# Weblogic 12c : Prefer-web-inf-classes and prefer-application-packages for Jersey

Tags: java, guice, weblogic12c, jersey-1.0, guice-servlet

I have to use both (oddly enough ..) `prefer-web-inf-classes` and `prefer-application-packages`  properties of *weblogic.xml* on a *Weblogic 12c Server (12.2.1)*

It is REST application based on Jersey 1.9. ( Jersey 1.x JAX-RS RI) and Guice.

**1. Why use :prefer-web-inf-classes**

If you have more than one WAR you have to place at the level of war/lib the  libraries for guice-jersey / guice  , other way you get an [Multibindings Error](https://github.com/google/guice/issues/559).

It must be indicated also the `prefer-web-inf-classes` to **`true`**.

This way it works properly!

I have tried to work in the same way using `prefer-application-package`s with packages (`com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.servlet`, `com.google.inject.servlet`, etc...) but no way.

Note: It is not possible to exclude this libraries at *EAR* level.

**2. Why use :prefer-application-packages**

To use Jersey 1.x JAX-RS RI on Weblogic 12c (12.2.1) so I have to indicate the following packages (*other way Weblogic uses Jersey 2, and different version of Jackson libraries, etc.* )

It works perfectly on Jersey 1.X if it is [indicated this way.](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/wls/RESTF/version-restful-service.htm#RESTF200) . I have probed two war separately, and works fine... but, remember my friend I have two war..so....

**Summary**

I can not use both properties (deploying error for using both properties on the weblogic.xml..), but it's needed :

1. For the problem with Guice Filter, need to put `prefer-web-inf-classes` to `true`to use `guice-servlet.jar` / `jersey-guice.jar` at  *war-lib level*.
2. To work with Jersey 1.x, need to use ..... `prefer-application-package`

**Question**: How to combine both to use one of them??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After all

1. Use just `prefer-web-inf-classes` to `true`.
2. If you use this, you don't need to use `prefer-application-packages` ....**BUT ENSURE that you have the correct libraries at war /ear level.**

   **The problem was:**

The Project had a dependency with  Jersey 2 (based on [Swagger](http://swagger.io/) for Jersey 2.X ...)  So via Swagger dependencies (`swagger-jersey2-jaxrs`),  Jersey 2 libraries was packaged on ear/war... and so `prefer-web-inf-classes` HAS NO EFFECT!

**After removing the dependency all was resolved!**

At same the level (classpath or ear lib, or war lib) should not exist different versions of the same library.

Comment: i  want my bounty back )) ! Nobody answered ))

Answer (score 0):

- Hello, world!
   Hi, There are two way to resolve this problem.

  1. You can used to combine both file in to one file and call it based on choose tag as requirements.
  2. You can just write tags to merge or import/ include your xml file in to one. Example shown.    
           
           
          Hint: Do google how to merge and call xml file based on condition.

Comment: Sorry, but this has no sense...The same weblogic.xml must be valid for both purposes, work with Jersey 1.X and  Jersey-Guice.