# weblogic.utils.compiler.ToolFailureException Weblogic 12.2.1

Tags: java, jdeveloper, weblogic12c

When deploying my application to Weblogic 12.2.1, I get this error:

```
weblogic.application.ModuleException:
weblogic.utils.compiler.ToolFailureException: Neither prefer-application-packages  
nor prefer-application-resources can be specified when prefer-web-inf-classes  
is turned on in weblogic.xml
```

In `weblogic.xml`, I have set prefer-web-inf-classes to true.

I use JDeveloper to deploy the application. Nowhere in my application's deployment descriptors (`web.xml` and `weblogic-application.xml`) do I use `prefer-application-packages` or `prefer-application-resources`. Why is Weblogic showing this error?

Regards, Jeroen

Comment: Got the same error. Nowhere in my war are those options set, but weblogic keeps failling to deploy the war. Did you managed to get this sorted out?

Answer (score 1):

If you have prefer-web-inf-classes to true so you can't use  prefer-application-packages. You have to use one of them but not both....

I had the same issue migrating from WL11  to WL12 :

[Weblogic 12c : Prefer-web-inf-classes and prefer-application-packages for Jersey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36292980/weblogic-12c-prefer-web-inf-classes-and-prefer-application-packages-for-jersey/36475057#36475057)

After all :

1. Use  just prefer-web-inf-classes to true.
2. If you use this, you don't need to use prefer-application-packages ....BUT ENSURE that you have the correct libraries at war /ear level.

Answer (score 0):

Check carefully, based on the documentation over here: [Deployment Descriptor Elements](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e21049/weblogic_xml.htm#WBAPP602), `A value specified in the Administration Console will take precedence over a value set manually.` So it must have been set somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

can you export your application to an ear file and there verify if there is no weblogic-application.xml with prefer-application-packages or prefer-application-resources tags ?

Jdeveloper creates automatically those files when there are any shared libraries, and could be the case.