# Weblogic: The servlet is referenced in servlet-mapping but not defined in web.xml

Tags: rest, jersey, weblogic

Getting this error why trying to deploy the war in weblogic

> Caused By: weblogic.management.DeploymentException: [HTTP:101170]The
>   servlet Web Rest Services is referenced in servlet-mapping /myrest/*
>   but not defined in web.xml.
>           at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.verifyServletMappings(WebAppServletContext.java:1465)
>           at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:2809)
>           at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1661)
>           at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:822)
>           at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$StartStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:360)

my web.xml:

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">
    <display-name>REST</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>rest.apis</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Web Rest Services</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/myrest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

If required I can paste the code of rest resources but not sure it matters.

What worries me, can there be issue with weblogic?

Note: Recently app server was upgraded to weblogic 12.1.2

Comment: `<servlet-name --> Jersey Web Application != Web Rest Services`

Comment: you think the Name labels should match? will try it soon...

Comment: Yes, this is the reason for the error. You are using a servlet-mapping with no servlet attached. This is because the name is different. Whether not this will get you running, I am not sure. You may still have more problems

Comment: man... checking the log of weblogic it seems it passed that point where it fails (it failed almost immediately) , it will take about 10 minutes,,,
if it works you are a genius :)

Comment: :) you may write it a answer :)
(will accept it tomorrow ) wasted 3 hours. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `<servlet-name --> Jersey Web Application != Web Rest Services`

The `<servlet-name>` in the `<servlet-mapping>` should correspond to a `<servlet-name>` in a `<servlet>` definition. Hence the error

> The servlet Web Rest Services is referenced in servlet-mapping /myrest/* but not defined in web.xml

Answer (score 1):

Try this configuration for your web.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
<display-name>NAME</display-name>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
           <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
           <param-value>YOUR REST CLASS PACKAGE</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/resources/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

And create an weblogic.xml file in the same folder (web-app\WEB-INF) like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<weblogic-web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app">
<library-ref>  
    <library-name>jax-rs</library-name>  
    <specification-version>2.0</specification-version>
    <implementation-version>2.5.1</implementation-version>  
    <exact-match>false</exact-match>
</library-ref>
<container-descriptor>
    <prefer-application-packages>
        <package-name>org.glassfish.jersey.media.*</package-name>
        <package-name>org.glassfish.jersey.client.*</package-name>
        <package-name>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.*</package-name> 
        <package-name>org.glassfish.jersey.jaxb.internal.*</package-name>   
        <package-name>com.sun.research.ws.wadl.*</package-name>
        <package-name>org.glassfish.hk2.*</package-name>
        <package-name>org.jvnet.hk2.*</package-name>
        <package-name>jersey.repackaged.org.objectweb.asm.*</package-name>
        <package-name>org.objectweb.asm.*</package-name>
        <package-name>com.sun.ws.rs.ext.*</package-name>
        <package-name>org.aopalliance.*</package-name>
        <package-name>javax.annotation.*</package-name>
        <package-name>javax.inject.*</package-name>
        <package-name>javax.ws.rs.*</package-name>
        <package-name>jersey.repackaged.com.google.common.*</package-name>
        <package-name>javassist.*</package-name>
    </prefer-application-packages>
</container-descriptor>
<context-root>YOUR_ROOT</context-root>
</weblogic-web-app>
```

Comment: Will do it, what is the reason can you explain?
also, url-pattern should be what I have right?

Comment: The reason for what?

Comment: Why need to load those classes?

Comment: I can confirm (checked) that above worked in previous weblogic version

Comment: now I am getting:
nresolved Webapp Library references for "WebAppModule(restful)", defined in weblogic.xml [Extension-Name: jax-rs, Specification-Version: 2, Implementation-Version: 2.5.1, exact-match: false

Comment: Because you have conflits between weblogic classes and your War classes. In prefer-application-packages you says to prefer your package classes

Comment: also, why can't I use jersey version 1.*? As I was using it before?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36292980/weblogic-12c-prefer-web-inf-classes-and-prefer-application-packages-for-jersey